# create JSON schema using StructType in Apacke Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to create StructType Schema for below JSON

```
{ 
   "countries":{ 
      "country":[ 
         { 
            "area":9596960,
            "cities":{ 

            },
            "name":"China",
            "population":1210004992
         },
         { 
            "area":3287590,
            "cities":{ 

            },
            "name":"India",
            "population":952107712
         },
         { 
            "area":9372610,
            "cities":{ 
               "city":[ 
                  { 
                     "name":"New York",
                     "population":7380906
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Los Angeles",
                     "population":3553638
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Chicago",
                     "population":2721547
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Detroit",
                     "population":1000272
                  }
               ]
            },
            "name":"United States",
            "population":266476272
         },
         { 
            "area":1919440,
            "cities":{ 
               "city":[ 
                  { 
                     "name":"Jakarta",
                     "population":8259266
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Surabaya",
                     "population":2483871
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Bandung",
                     "population":2058649
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Medan",
                     "population":1730752
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Semarang",
                     "population":1250971
                  },
                  { 
                     "name":"Palembang",
                     "population":1144279
                  }
               ]
            },
            "name":"Indonesia",
            "population":206611600
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I'm doing below code to get all countries name

```
DataTypes.createStructField("countries", (new StructType()).add(DataTypes.createStructField("country",
                    (new StructType()).add(DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true)), true)), true)
```

But when am running below to get all country names

```
Dataset<Row> namesDF = spark.sql("SELECT countries FROM country");
        namesDF.show();
```

I'm getting `nulls`, May I know please how to parse Json fields to get values using StructType ..?

The am doing, Is it the correct way of doing it ..? I'm trying to get country names from above JSON

Update:

Code:

```
    static final StructType SCHEMA = new StructType(new StructField[] {

            DataTypes.createStructField("countries",
                    new StructType().add(DataTypes.createStructField("country",
                            new ArrayType(new StructType()
                                    .add(DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true)), true),
                            true)),
                    true) }

    );

}
```

Entry Point

```
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().schema(Jsonreadystructure.SCHEMA)
                .json(context.getProperty(GlobalConstants.ReadyJsonFile));

        ds.printSchema();

        ds.createOrReplaceTempView("country_data");
        ds.sqlContext().sql("SELECT country.name FROM country_data lateral view explode(countries.country) t as country").show(false);
```

Output

```
root
 |-- countries: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)

+----+
|name|
+----+
+----+
```

Why Its showing empty name..? I'm using spark 2.4.4

Schema Discovery

```
root
 |-- countries: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- area: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- population: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your json `country` field contains array not struct, so it leads to schema mismatch. You should create schema with `ArrayType` like this:

```
DataTypes.createStructField("countries", 
    new StructType().add(DataTypes.createStructField("country",
                    new ArrayType(new StructType().add(DataTypes.createStructField("name", 
    DataTypes.StringType, true)), true), true)), true)
```

With this schema you will get countries as follows:

```
df.registerTempTable("country_data");
spark.sql("SELECT countries FROM country_data").show();
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|countries                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray([China], [India], [United States], [Indonesia])]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In case you want to list all countries inside the array you should use `explode`:

```
spark.sql("SELECT country.name FROM country_data lateral view explode(countries.country) t as country").show(false)
+-------------+
|name         |
+-------------+
|China        |
|India        |
|United States|
|Indonesia    |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Its show no entries in output, please check the update in question.

Comment: What is `GlobalConstants.ReadyJsonFile`? Does your file contain pretty formatted json (like on your post) or it contains one-line json?

Comment: The problem was my JSON was not one-liner JSON, that's why it failing. May I know please, why is it so ..?

Comment: Can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466021/not-able-to-catch-nested-element-of-json  I'm almost done with extraction but got stuck in one nested element

Comment: @JonLe Your code looks very complicated. Why don't you use schema discovery?  I mean `val schema = spark.read.json(Seq(json).toDS.rdd).schema.json` and than `org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.fromJson(schema)`?

Comment: I did schema discovery like you said, updated in question. But why am not able to see city's name and population ..? Its present in JSON

Comment: @JonLe It looks like you json data has items with different `cities` schema. When I try to make schema discovery on json with single line from your post I got `countries-> country-> element-> cities-> city-> element->name and population` but in your code I see `cities->city` which is string. It means some lines could contain non arrays (i.e. string or nested struct). In such cases spark merges schema into `string` type

Comment: So is there any way I could consider city always as Array even if they dont have different cities in it ..?

Comment: @JonLe try to use the only one line for schema discovery. But anyway if your data has different schema, your query will not return data for some rows...

Comment: "one line for schema discovery." meaning ..?